# Is the Content-Length header required for a HTTP/1.0 response?

Tags: http, http-headers

Is the `Content-Length` header required for a HTTP/1.0 response? The HTTP spec mentions that it is required for the request, but doesn't mention anything about the response:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Content-Length

> A valid Content-Length field value is required on all HTTP/1.0
>   request messages containing an entity body.

If it is not required for the response, how does the client read the response when it's larger than 1MB?

Comment: For requesters, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14758729/632951

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Section 10.4 of the spec (which you linked to) doesn't say anything about requirements on responses itself, but instead links to [section 7.2.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#BodyLength), which specifies that the server can indicate the length of a response containing an entity body by

- sending a `Content-Length` header, or
- closing the connection when the entire response has been sent.

[Section 7.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Entity-Body) says that responses to `HEAD` requests, and 1xx, 204 or 304 responses, should not include an entity body, and therefore need not include a `Content-Length` header; and

> All other responses must include an entity body or a `Content-Length` header field defined with a value of zero (0).

So to answer the question: When no `Content-Length` is received, the client keeps reading until the server closes the connection.

Comment: The conclusion in the end is not completely accurate I believe. "The client keeps reading until the server closes the connection, or the announced content-length has been received; After which the (tcp) connection can be used for another request." Let me know if I'm making mistakes here.

Comment: @KemHeyndels Well, the question basically asked what happened when there *wasn't* a `Content-Length` header, so…

Comment: @KemHeyndels I've clarified the answer a little; it *was* written in my newbie days, and perhaps a bit unclear. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: I learned (the hard way) that if a response is "large," including Content-Length can prevent issues. Not sure what "large" is, but it my API started working for responses over 100k when I included it.

Comment: @ScottyB Makes sense - probably something was defaulting to a 100k buffer.

Comment: especially on android, having Content-Length is mandatory. I learnt that the hard way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685816/android-could-not-receive-form-submit-response

Without the Content-Type, android gives an exception if server closes connection (reads the data, then shouts exception). Problem went away as soon as Content-Type was put. Its one of those non standard things which different libraries may want to be mandatory, so its always better to put it, even if rfc doesnt mandate it