# Java Sockets - Hang on reading data from server

Tags: java, sockets

I'm currently working on a little Client/Server task with using sockets.
Sadly I the client hangs when it is supposed to read the "200 OK File Created" sent by the server. Is there anything i overlooked? 
Client:

```
public HTTPClient(InetAddress adress, int portnumber, String filename) throws IOException {
    socket = new Socket(adress, portnumber);
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    this.filename = filename;
}

public void sendPutRequest() throws IOException {
    output.println("PUT /" + filename + " HTTP/1.0");
    output.flush();
    File myFile = new File(this.filename);
    if (myFile.exists()) {
        for (String string : Files.readAllLines(myFile.toPath())) {
            output.println(string);
        }
        output.flush();
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } else {
        throw new IOException("File not found");
    }
}
```

Server:

```
  try (Socket client = this.socket.accept(); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream())) {

    String lineIn = in.readLine();
    if (lineIn.contains("PUT")) {
        String filename = lineIn.split(" ")[1].substring(1);
        List<String> filedata = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            filedata.add(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        writeToFile(filename, filedata);
        out.println("200 OK File Created");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems like no connection established.  what's your `output` instance?

Comment: Same as on the Server. I use a PrintWriter there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is reading from the connection until it is closed (only in such a case `in.readLine()`will return `null`).

However your client does not close the connection to the server. Therefore the server is stuck in the while loop.

Solution: You have to close the `output` stream after sending the request. Alternatively detect the end of the request on server side without waiting for the "end of stream" limit.

Comment: Note: Usually with HTTP the `Content-Length:` header will show how long the body is and where it ends.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991173/is-the-content-length-header-required-for-a-http-1-0-response for details.

Comment: If i would close the connection rightaway, I wouldn't be able to send the client an acknowledge afterwards or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Nevermind i got i now. I transfered the number of lines before doing any reading on the server side. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ebyrob: We are talking about the code reading the request, not the response. AFAIR in HTTP the request end is indicated by two empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

In your server code:

```
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                filedata.add(line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
             writeToFile(filename, filedata); // getting to this line?
```

Your server is never getting to the writeToFile line, because the socket connection is still open, and it's still in the while loop. As a solution, use  [DataFetcher](https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java)