# Android could not receive form submit response

Tags: android, sockets, post, inputstream

I have a python webserver, which is listening for connections, and responds to them based on the request. The portion of code on python server of interest is POST request (http://192.168.0.1/conf_wifi_app.html). It takes 4 arguments

1. username (admin)
2. password (admin)
3. essid (Home wifi network SSID)
4. passphrase (Home wifi network password)

On python server, after the post body parameters are validated, a response is to be sent like so (notice I've put logs for debugging):

```
json_response = '{"error":false,' + '"code":"' + str(activation_code) + '","mac":"' + str(macaddress) + '","message":"Device configured successfully"}'
bytes_sent = client_s.send(json_response)
client_s.close()
print("Bytes sent " + str(bytes_sent))
print("json_response : " + json_response)
```

where client_s is the client socket. "send" function on socket should send the response (json_response), and then we close the socket. Logs print the number of bytes which is actually sent.

The client responds perfectly well when POST request is done from the web browser or from postman plugin. Just for some reference, I've put the raw request when invoked from postman plugin on chrome browser:

```
POST /conf_wifi_app.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 67
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/68.0.3440.75 Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Postman-Token: 4f4a14a7-857d-666f-a2db-279731c83b4a
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: /
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

essid=NETGEAR-XXXX&passphrase=XXXXXXXX&username=admin&password=admin&submit=submit
```

The response is received when the POST request is made from web browser (or postman). Now I was trying to create an android app which does the same POST request as follows:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

try {

    Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("user", Constants.DEVICE_DEFAULT_USER);
    params.put("username", Constants.DEVICE_DEFAULT_USER);
    params.put("password", Constants.DEVICE_DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
    params.put("essid", homeWifiSSID.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", ""));
    params.put("passphrase", homeWifiPassword);

    StringBuilder urlParameters = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (urlParameters.length() != 0) urlParameters.append('&');
        urlParameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        urlParameters.append('=');
        urlParameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }
    byte[] postData = urlParameters.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    int    postDataLength = postData.length;

    URL url = new URL(Constants.DEVICE_CONFIG_URL);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) network.openConnection(url);

    urlConnection.setDoInput( true );
    urlConnection.setDoOutput( true );
    urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    urlConnection.setUseCaches( false );

    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(OuroborosAPI.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(OuroborosAPI.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

    try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( urlConnection.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.write( postData );
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
    }

    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;) {
        System.out.print((char) c);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

From android app, the post raw data received is as follows:

```
POST /conf_wifi.html HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
charset: utf-8
Content-Length: 85
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; Moto G (5S) Plus Build/NPSS26.116-61-11)
Host: 192.168.0.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip

essid=NETGEAR-XXXX&passphrase=XXXXXXXX&username=admin&password=admin&submit=submit
```

The python socket in this case does send data (as confirmed from the logs), but the android errors out saying **unexpected end of string**.

I've literally tried every thing (like adding extra headers, etc) but to no avail. Please help or suggest where I may be going wrong.

Comment: Use in.readLine() instead.

Comment: @greenapps, I'll try that, but any reason why you suggest that? Why it won't work with usual read()?

Comment: You should always use readLine() if you expect text. Nothing else.

Comment: Then tell what the server sends and what the client receives.

Comment: The deadline() thing doesn't work. It's failing in Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));. Doesn't even get to read()

Comment: @greenapps, can you think of why it may be failing during initialization of Reader?

Comment: Then you will have an exception. Which?

Comment: Unexpected end of stream

Comment: `wr.close();`. Remove that.

Comment: Tried that too, didn't solve

Comment: @greenapps, I'm thinking of using basic sockets now to achieve this, since it's not working. Do you think it's worth a shot?

Comment: No. Of course not. Try to find out why it does not work for you.

Comment: I have tried literally everything. Do you think not sending any new line or NULL terminated characters at end is causing this problem?

Comment: Can you give me any insights @greenapps? I'm really out of clue now. Having spent a lot of time, cannot think of any case. It works perfectly fine on chrome browser or from postman.

Comment: There's one more thing @greenapps. The response does not have HTML raw header data. Should I also add those?

Comment: @greenapps, I've seen you suggest things like always using readline on similar questions too. There's no such restrictions purely from socket perspective. I request you to refrain from sending incorrect info without any basis

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not that I was not sending \n ended lines, or not using readline()

I was not sending the HTML raw headers like so

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Length: 9328
  Content-Type: text/html

... Actual content/payload....

Once I sent the headers also, the code worked without any problems.