# PSR-7 Responses: how to send a proper Content-Length if the body is a stream of unknown length?

Tags: php, json, performance, stream, psr-7

This is more a theoretical question, because I want to implement a way to deal with big arrays of objects that need to be converted to json using `json_encode` and I want to avoid having the whole array of results in memory to convert the whole thing (it could lead into memory issues).

What I want to do is having a PSR-7 body stream that internally (somehow) fetches, converts and outputs one result at a time. The problem about doing this is that I don't know beforehand the final response `Content-Length`.

Someone has faced the same problem? How can I compute/add that header without proxying that to an intermediate service that would add/fix the `Content-Length` header?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
Possible solution: chunked responses.

I think I found a possible solution for this, and it is using chunked responses.
I still need to figure out how to use that with JSON responses and what the API clients should change in order to support them.

[HTTP POST: content-length header required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758729/http-post-content-length-header-required)

Anyway if someone has faced the same problem and has a PSR-7 compatible solution I would like to know about that.

Comment: Does PSR-7 require a Content-Length? Why do you need it?

Comment: No, but clients using my API do somehow, and it is anyway required in the HTTP 1.1 spec